# Crystal Reports changes text to lower case

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have text objects on a Crystal Report in Visual Studio with an initial capital. When I print the report, the text is all lower case.

And the reason is?

Comment: Are these static text objects or are their values being set using an expression?

Comment: Does it do this when you export the report to also?

Comment: @SeaDrive, could you provide an update on this question?

Comment: It happened once, and not again. One of those mysteries...

Answer (score 1):

We have found a workaround for this problem. Not sure how this works :) - can any expert explain?

We found that this problem of case change was happening whenever the extent of text within any page / section of the report was going beyond the settings of the page size minus gutter, left/right margins, top/bottom margins set for the report.

As a workaround, we have asked all our reports developers to keep the text (for A4 size reports) to within 7.5 inches X 7.5 inches. The problem does not happen when this is adhered to.

Would definitely like to know exact reasons for the misbehavior though.

Comment: maybe it's a feature.  lower case is generally skinnier than CAPS

Answer (score -3):

This might be affecting by some of the settings.
But if you go and edit the field , you can see it automatically change to lowercase.
If you agains change it back your case, then it will work fine.

It looks like it happend for one time. To be honest, I don't know why this happend

Comment: this should be a comment, answer should only answer the question. Adittional informatie should be added as a comment. You can post comments if you have a reputation of 50, until then you shouldn't post comments as answers.